We know if $||A||$ is operator norm of $A$, then $||Ax|| \leq ||A||.||x||$ Is there any general rule when does it hold with equality for all $x$?
We know if $||A||$ is operator norm of $A$, then
$||Ax|| \leq ||A||.||x||$ Is there any general rule when does it hold with equality for all $x$
For example: if $A$ is k$I$ for any scaler $k$, it trivially holds. Is there any other characterisation of $A$?

You need $A$ to be a multiple of a (linear) isometry (e.g. $I$, but not necessarily just $I$). When in an inner product space, this is equivalent to $A$ being a multiple of an orthogonal operator.

It suffices to consider the case when $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$ for all $x$. Note that $\|Ax\|=\|x\| \iff \langle Ax, Ax \rangle =\langle x, x \rangle \iff \langle A^*Ax, x \rangle =\langle x, x \rangle \iff \langle (A^*A-I)x, x \rangle =0$ for all $x$ which holds if and only if $A^*A=I$.
